# Print output log from folder watcher to browser window using Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to print out logs from folder watcher to broswer-window using Electron.
I can print out logs in terminal but do not know print logs to browserwindow.

I want to print out logs from folder watcher to broswer-window using Electron.
I can print out logs in terminal but do not know print logs to browserwindow.

[See this image for my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpTzQ.png)

here is my source. How can I implement it?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <head>

 <title>Hello World!</title>

 </head>

 <body>

 I learned about Electron in Visual Studio Code<br />

 from <a href="http://www.mylifeforthecode.com">My Life For The Code</a>.

 <script>require('./watch.js')</script>
 </body>

</html>
```

main.js

```js
var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app;

var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {

 if (process.platform != 'darwin')

 app.quit();

});

app.on('ready', function() { 

 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600}); 

 mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html'); 
 mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

 mainWindow.on('closed', function() {

 mainWindow = null;

 }); 

});
```

watch.js

```js
var watch = require('node-watch');
 
watch('./', { recursive: true }, function(evt, name) {

    if (evt == 'update') {
        console.log('%s updated.', name);
        // on create or modify
    }

    if (evt == 'remove') {
        console.log('%s removed.', name);
      // on delete
    }
    
 // console.log('%s changed.', name);
});
```

Comment: Is there any specific problem with that code?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hi I do not know how to print logs to browser....I can show logs in terminal but don't know how to print logs to browser UI. is there any example code?

Comment: `console.log` prints stuff to the browsers console

Comment: @NicoHaase Not for console. I want to print stuffs to 'window'

Comment: Okay, so you don't want to put it to the developer tools, but to anything within the DOM?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes. that's what I want :)